# wget No Long Working On Specific Website

Tags: macos, terminal, openssl, wget

I have used `wget` to scrape https://kenpom.com/ in the past with no problem, but now it won't work for me. There is a password protected portion of the website, which is why I use `wget`, but now I can't even scrape the public part of the website. When I run the code

```
/usr/local/bin/wget -O /Users/dwm8/Desktop/file.txt https://kenpom.com/
```

I get the following:

```
--2018-03-13 12:53:59--  https://kenpom.com/
Resolving kenpom.com (kenpom.com)... 67.227.157.91
Connecting to kenpom.com (kenpom.com)|67.227.157.91|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Is there a workaround to this? I'm using OSX 10.13.3 and `wget` version 1.15. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you use `curl -L https://kenpom.com/` ? It seems to give you the result.

Comment: That works for the homepage, but then when I try to use `curl` on one of the password protected pages, for example `curl -u username:password https://kenpom.com/team.php?team=Virginia`, I get nothing. I have a cookies.txt file with my login info that I've tried to read in but that isn't working either

Comment: I'd be happy to use `curl` to scrape it, but I'm not sure how to use it to work on the pages that require a login

Comment: You can tell `curl` to use your cookies.txt file with the `-b` and `-c` command-line arguments. `-b cookies.txt` tells it to read `cookies.txt` for cookies relevant to your URL, and `-c cookies.txt` tells it to write any new or updated cookies into the same file. However, it isn't clear why the `wget` in your original request is failing. If you're still having this issue, can you add a `-d` to your wget command line to produce debug-level output for analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome/Firefox extension [cookies.txt](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-txt/) to export the cookie that is generated after logging into the website.

Now use `curl` with syntax `curl -L -b /path/to/cookies.txt {url}` this should do the trick.

It has worked for me so far.